# Difference between DiskReadBytes metric for EC2 instance and VolumeReadBytes metric for EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to understand EBS metrics,but i am confused between some metrics in EC2 and EBS, and also difference between Disk and Volume?
Taking example of DiskReadBytes metric in EC2 Instance and VolumeReadBytes metric in EBS ,explain me difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `DiskReadBytes`
>
> Bytes read from all instance store volumes available to the instance.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html

The important phrase is **instance store volumes**.

Some EC2 instance types can be provisioned to have one or more drives physically installed in the host system and dedicated to your VM.  These are called [*ephemeral* or *instance store*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) volumes.  Their contents are transient -- lost if the virtual machine is stopped or the host hardware fails... but they also tend to be extremely fast (high throughput and low latency) so they are good for things like swap, temporary scratch space, or non-authoritative database replicas, but they are not durable like EBS and do not support snapshots like EBS -- these volumes, if your instance has them, are not EBS volumes.

tl;dr: The EC2 `DiskReadBytes` metric includes only the traffic for disks that are not EBS volumes, and excludes EBS disk traffic.